# Overwrite Resources in Windows 10

Tags: windows, resources, uwp

I have the following simplified scenario:
A Windows 10 Class Library containing a UserControl with an Image Control that displays an image from a file inside the library: 

`<Image Source="Assets/myimage.png"></Image>`

 Now I have different App-Projects (UWP) containing this library and displaying my Image Control.

In these Projects are different images that should replace the original `myimage.png`. Simply putting the new image in `Assets` Folder of my App-Project does not work (thats the way it works in Android).

Summary: I want to replace a Image-File in a Library with a file in my actual App-Project.


 Edit:
The Control inside the Library:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="mLib.TestImageView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="Image" Source="Assets/myimage.png"></Image>
</Grid>
```

Usage Inside the App:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <mlibrary:TestImageView/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you give us, the library, language? some code?

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: Honestly I do not know, is it a path problem with separator: \ vs / , or right problem? or finally a relative/absolute path? As it look it should replace your images.

Comment: If i set the property in the app project again, with the same path, it works fine. But that is not really a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put slash in the beginning, like this:

```
<Image x:Name="Image" Source="/Assets/myimage.png"></Image>
```

Replacing will work fine then. But I don't think you'll be able to use original image in referencing projects after that.

Comment: Jep, it just uses the Image from my App but not from the library. If the App is missing the picture it shwos nothing.